# Handling Mismatch Between Domain and Code First Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, separation-of-concerns

I am using Code First approach and there are some *mismatch between my model for code first approach (DAL) and my domain model (BLL)*. I imagine my Data Model to have annotations, properties, configurations, etc related to database only and not the same for my Domain model entities and vice versa to obey separation of concerns.

How do I go about handling this situation in my application? This is more logical then technical I guess. Asked before in many places but no concrete lead yet. Hope some suggestion from SO will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience because of the rich mapping possibilities of the Entity Framework you don't have to separate a Data access and Business logic layer at all, you just have to use the Fluent API of the Entity Framework. In one of my current project we have more than 150 classes with inheritance hierarchies and all but we can still use it without "duplicating" the objects.

Some good introductions about the fluent API can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852588.aspx

About the separation: we simply use a Domain project and a Persistence.EntityFramework project where the latter contains all the mappings thus the Domain does not reference the EntityFramework.dll at all.

And if you have some specific mapping questions e.g. the ones you mentioned that are the reasons you created two layers one for DAL and the other for BL just ask them.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go this way for now and if I do have any mapping question I will knock you through your blog :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help and if you have any question just shoot that to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with AutoMapper. It can help you to reduce the boilerplate code needed to convert from one object to another.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Edit:

Put your domain models either in BLL or in a separate project, add reference to the BLL or this separate project in the DAL (also reference the new project in BLL), and use the AutoMapper in the DAL. So only domain models will leave the DAL.

Comment: My question is related to HOW rather than WHAT. Can you please link to a sample or article that would discuss this in detail?

Comment: Yes. This is one approach I guess. I want business models/logic should be independent of anything. Won't this add dependency in my BLL?

Comment: Nope. If you put the domain models in the BLL, then only DAL will depend on the BLL.
In my opinion separating the models in a new project is even nicer, because you do not have to reference the BLL, just the models.

Answer (score 0):

You normally have:

- A domain model (entities), which is what the O/RM (Entity Framework) uses;
- A Data Transfer Objects (DTO) model, used for sending data to a view (in MVC) or by web services, etc.

I agree with Andras: the best way to go from one (domain) to the other (DTO) is by using Automapper. Of course, you can also do it by hand.
One thing that you need to realize is that there is no need for a 1-1 mapping between the domain and the DTO, the DTO can contain denormalized or calculated properties as well.

Comment: Like I said my domain models/business logic might not have 1:1 mapping with the model that will represent my Code First approach to DB. AFAIK DTOs are concerned in UI layer (Web, API, etc) maybe but atm I am trying to decouple my DAL and BLL as I stated above.